# How to write a command line tool using bash

Tags: bash

I want to write a command line tool like git which will follow the `POSIX` standards. It will take the options like `--help` or `-h` , `--version` ..etc. But i am not getting how to do it. Can anybody tell me how to do this using bash scripting. Please help me. This is something very new to me.

Example : if the name of my tool is Check-code then i want to use the tool like ;

```
Check-code --help
```

or

```
Check-code --version
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8533029/bash-multiple-command-line-arguments-dependent-on-each-other?rq=1

Answer (score 7):

So far as I know, "long options", like `--help` and `--version` are not POSIX standard, but GNU standard.  For command-line utilities the POSIX standard says:

*The arguments that consist of hyphens and single letters or digits, such as 'a', are known as "options" (or, historically, "flags").*

To support POSIX short options options it is worth getting to know `getopts` (there are tutorials on the web), but it does not support GNU long options.

For long options you have to roll your own:

```
filename=default
while (( $# > 0 ))
do
    opt="$1"
    shift

    case $opt in
    --help)
        helpfunc
        exit 0
        ;;
    --version)
        echo "$0 version $version"
        exit 0
        ;;
    --file)  # Example with an operand
        filename="$1"
        shift
        ;;
    --*)
        echo "Invalid option: '$opt'" >&2
        exit 1
        ;;
    *)
        # end of long options
        break;
        ;;
   esac

done
```

Comment: I think this can be one of the way to achieve the long options. Using getopt can we make it short and working for both short and long options

Comment: @user1497818: very difficult, I can't see a way of using `getopts` with long options.  You might be better off using Perl and `Getopt::Long` http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html

Comment: You could detect a single dash in the case and pass $opt and $1 (in case there is an argument to the option) to getopts for it to handle. The only advantage gained is the ability to handle multiple single-letter options passed as a group (e.g. -ine == -i -n -e). I've never had anyone request that ability for any tool I've written so I've never bothered to support it.

Comment: for long/short, just use | i.e. `version|-v|--version)`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the 'getopts' builtin, like so:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Parse arguments
usage() {
    echo "Usage: $0 [-h] [-v] [-f FILE]"
    echo "  -h  Help. Display this message and quit.
    echo "  -v  Version. Print version number and quit.
    echo "  -f  Specify configuration file FILE."
    exit
}

optspec="hvf:"
while getopts "$optspec" optchar
do
    case "${optchar}" in
        h)
            usage
            ;;
        v)
            version
            ;;
        f)
            file=${OPTARG}
            ;;
        *)
            usage
            ;;
    esac
done
```

This only works for single character options, not for long options like `-help` or `--help`. In practice, I've never found that this is a significant restriction; any script which is complex enough to require long options is probably something that I would write in a different language.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a better way to do this, but here is what I find useful:
Each argument is represented by a variable in BASH.  The first argument is `$1`.  The second is `$2`, and so on.  Match an option string with the first argument, and if it matches run some code accordingly.

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $1 == "--hello" ] 
    then
        echo "Hello"
    else
        echo "Goodbye"
fi
```

If you code in C or C++, then use the `**argv` variable.  `**argv` is a double pointer that holds a list of all arguments passed to the program (with `argv[0]` being the program name).

Comment: thanks for the reply.I think we can use the bash command "getopt" . Can you propose the solution of above using that. But i don't know whether it works for both "-h" and "--help" kind of formats

Comment: If using the Bourne shell style `test` (`[`) you should quote the `"$1"`.  Using `[[` does not require quotes around the variable (but still need quotes around a literal containing white-space).